# Adding a folder generated at runtime as source folder using Ant in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, classpath

I am using the following bunch of softwares:

1. Ant 1.7.1
2. Eclipse Helios
3. Java 1.6
4. Apache thrift 0.8.0

I am using Thrift to generate java source code in Ant using the following code block:

```
<exec executable="thrift-0.8.0.exe" osfamily="windows">
    <arg value="-out" />
    <arg value="java/src" />
    <arg value="--gen" />
    <arg value="java" />
    <arg file="Sample.thrift" />
</exec>
```

So, now I want to `add` the generated `src` folder automatically to the `classpath` of the project `in Eclipse using Ant` so that it is `shown as a source folder` when I open the project in Eclipse.

**NOTE:** I understand that the classpath for a project is present in the `.classpath` file and `adding a classpathentry` to it would solve my issue. But I want Eclipse to do that instead of me doing it in the .classpath file manually.

Further, I also had a look at the [Ant-Eclipse project](http://ant-eclipse.sourceforge.net/) and found an Ant task to create a new Eclipse Java project and display its `src` folder as a source folder. But I don't want a dependency on an external library.

```
<project name="test" default="eclipse" basedir=".">
    <target name="eclipse">
        <taskdef name="eclipse" classname="prantl.ant.eclipse.EclipseTask" />
        <eclipse>
            <project />
            <classpath>
                <source path="src" />
                <output path="bin" />
            </classpath>
        </eclipse>
    </target>
</project>
```

Is there a way to do this in the already existing Ant library in Eclipse?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really don't want to depend on anything external then you could consider using an XSLT stylesheet to edit the `.classpath` file (which is XML).

**add-dir.xsl**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:param name="pathToAdd" />

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="classpath">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
      <!-- don't add a 2nd copy of the classpathentry if one already exists -->
      <xsl:if test="not(classpathentry[@kind = 'src'][@path = $pathToAdd])">
        <classpathentry kind="src" path="{$pathToAdd}" />
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**build.xml**

```
<xslt in=".classpath" out=".classpath.edited" style="add-dir.xsl">
  <param name="pathToAdd" expression="java/src" />
</xslt>
<move file=".classpath.edited" tofile=".classpath" overwrite="yes" />
```

Comment: A solution which is very innovative and i couldn't have thought of!!

Answer (score 1):

The eclipse .classpath file is an XML document, so adding a source folder in there involves editing XML.  Unfortunately, Ant doesn't have any built-in facilities for manipulating XML in any meaningful way.  I've used [xmltask](http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/) for editing .classpath and .project files myself, but that's an external library you said you don't really want.

All is not lost, however - [Ant supports running scripts](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/script.html), including [Groovy, which treats XML as a first-class citizen](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Updating+XML+with+XmlParser).  I wish I could say I had enough experience with Groovy to give you more than some links, but what you're after looks very doable with some calls to `appendNode()`.